# Rows lost during merge in R

Tags: r, merge, rows

I'm working with `df1` that contains 180K rows and 27 factors.  I used 3 factors in a merge with `df2` (43K obs, 10 factors, 3 factors match with `df1`). In `df1`, the rows are observations repeated over months for several years for `TrapLines` and `TrapNum`.  There are 3393 unique levels associated with `TrapLines` & `TrapNum`. In `df2`, `Shade` varies by month for `TrapLine` and `Trapnum`: for each `TrapLine`/`Trapnum` entry, there are 12 values of `Shade`.  In `df2`, there are 3268 unique levels associated with `Trapline`/`Trapnum`.  I want to merge (if that's the correct process) `df1` and `df2` such that the monthly `Shade` data is associated with the correct `Trapline`/`TrapNum` in `df1`.

df1:

```
TrapLine    TrapNum Date        Month_num
A24         D101    1-1-2018       1
A24         D101    2-13-2017      2
A24         D102    3-30-2017      3
A24         D102    4-10-2019      4
A24         D103    4-10-2019      4
A24         D103    5-15-2016      6
```

etc.

df2:

```
TrapLine    TrapNum Shade      Month    Month_num
A24         D101    217         Jan      1
A24         D101    201         Feb      2
A24         D101    172         Mar      3
A24         D102    145         Mar      3
A24         D102    97          Apr      4
A24         D102    59          May      5
```

etc.

I used the following code:

```
df3 <- merge (df1, df2, by c("TrapLine", "TrapNum", "Month_num"))
```

However, in the process, I lose 40K observations from `df1`!  I'm at a loss to explain what happened: I would've thought that if there weren't matches between `TrapLine`/`TrapNum` that the `Shade` values would've been set to `NA` or the like, not that observations would be lost altogether.  Can someone please help me understand what's happened and what process could be used such that I retain all of the observations (I'll worry about eliminating observations without Shade later!).  Thank you for your time and attention.
Cheers, Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the argument `all` of the `merge` function. By default, `all=FALSE`, so it does a "inner join", and drops all unmatched observations. If you set `merge(..., all=TRUE)` you have a "outer join" and keep all observations.  See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/merge

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  I'm on my way...for the moment.